# How can I use the Table command to produce a Table of specific values from a 2 variables function?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to  use the "Table" command to produce a `Table` of specific values from the following 2 variables  function :

```
(x^(1/4))*(y^(3/4))
```

The specific values are the 5 following pairs :

```
{x=0,y=0},
{x=1/4,y=1/28},
{x=1/2,y=1/10},
{x=3/4,y=1/4},
{x=1,y=1}
```

The result should be :

```
{0, 1/(4 7^(1/4)), 1/(2 5^(1/4)), 3^(3/4)/4, 1}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** If you don't have to use `Table` then, among many alternatives, you can use

```
#[[1]]^(1/4) #[[2]]^(3/4) & @ Transpose[xypairs]
```

> {0, 1/(4 7^(3/4)), 1/(2 5^(3/4)), 3^(1/4)/4, 1}

Or

```
#[[1]] #[[2]]& @ ((Transpose @ xypairs)^{1/4, 3/4})
```

> same result

**Some timings:**

```
f1 = Table[(i[[1]]^(1/4))*(i[[2]]^(3/4)), {i, #}] &;
f2 = Table[(#[[i, 1]]^(1/4))*(#[[i, 2]]^(3/4)), {i,  Length@#}] &;
f3 = #[[1]]^(1/4) #[[2]]^(3/4) & @ Transpose[#] &;
f4 = Cases[#, {x_, y_} :> x^(1/4) y^(3/4)] &; (* from @Mr. Wizard's answer *)
f5 = #^(1/4) #2^(3/4) & @@@ # &; (* from @Mr. Wizard's answer *)
f6= #[[1]] #[[2]]& @ ((Transpose @ #)^{1/4, 3/4})&;

SeedRandom[1]
vals = RandomReal[1, {100000, 2}];
t1 = First[RepeatedTiming[r1 = f1@vals;]];
t2 = First[RepeatedTiming[r2 = f2@vals;]];
t3 = First[RepeatedTiming[r3 = f3@vals;]];
t4 = First[RepeatedTiming[r4 = f4@vals;]]; 
t5 = First[RepeatedTiming[r5 = f5@vals;]]; 
t6 = First[RepeatedTiming[r6 = f6@vals;]];

r1 == r2 == r3 == r4 == r5 ==r6
```

> True

```
Prepend[SortBy[Transpose[{{ "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6"},
  { t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6}}], Last], {"function", "timing"}] // 
    Grid[#, Dividers -> All] & // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{function} & \text{timing} \\
> \hline
>  \text{f3} & 0.00965 \\
> \hline
>  \text{f6} & 0.108 \\
> \hline
>  \text{f5} & 0.277 \\
> \hline
>  \text{f4} & 0.294 \\
> \hline
>  \text{f1} & 0.297 \\
> \hline
>  \text{f2} & 0.317 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

**Original answer:**

```
xvalues = Range[0, 1, 1/4];
yvalues = {0, 1/28, 1/10, 1/4, 1};
xypairs = Transpose[{xvalues, yvalues}];
Table[(i[[1]]^(1/4))*(i[[2]]^(3/4)), {i, xypairs}]
```

> {0, 1/(4 7^(3/4)), 1/(2 5^(3/4)), 3^(1/4)/4, 1}

or

```
Table[(xypairs[[i, 1]]^(1/4))*(xypairs[[i, 2]]^(3/4)), {i, Length @ xypairs}]
```

> same result

Comment: `xvalues^(1/4)*yvalues^(3/4)`

Comment: @BobHanlon, yes. But `xvalues` and `yvalues` are available only after `Transpose`ing the list of pairs.

Answer (score 4):

You did not explain why you want to use [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html), and it does not appear to be the correct tool for this job.  Two alternatives for you to consider:

```
vals = {{0, 0}, {1/4, 1/28}, {1/2, 1/10}, {3/4, 1/4}, {1, 1}};

#^(1/4) #2^(3/4) & @@@ vals

Cases[vals, {x_, y_} :> x^(1/4) y^(3/4)]
```

> ```
> {0, 1/(4 7^(3/4)), 1/(2 5^(3/4)), 3^(1/4)/4, 1}
>
> {0, 1/(4 7^(3/4)), 1/(2 5^(3/4)), 3^(1/4)/4, 1}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly this is a very slow solution, but half for the sake of covering alternatives and half because I thing has an intuitive side to it to keep the named variables.

Using

```
vals = {{0, 0}, {1/4, 1/28}, {1/2, 1/10}, {3/4, 1/4}, {1, 1}};
```

### [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html)

```
rule = Thread[{x, y} -> #] & /@ vals
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And therefore,

```
(x^(1/4))*(y^(3/4)) /. Dispatch[rule]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And also

### [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)

```
Function[{x, y}, (x^(1/4))*(y^(3/4))] @@@ vals
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice use of list replacement.